# Triangle progression: triangle count and image of result

Tags: geometry

In the middle of an evenly spaced grid of points I draw one triangle. How many triangles are touching my first triangle? How many triangles touch that first set? How many triangles touch those triangles and so on. The number of adjacent triangles moving away as a series count would be nice (up to 10 steps). What is the shape of the result? A picture with each set a different color would make it so easy to see what is going on.
The use is in 3-D modeling of physical geometry with polygon meshes. I want to play "connect the dots" with an evenly spaced grid of 3D data, which once initialized I can "pick up" and bend the mesh by manipulating my first "control" triangle. I want to see the influence of moving my first constructed triangle, how much the "stretching" of leg lengths would propagate and how far it would go if all legs has the same modulus of elasticity to contribute in absorption of a big translation of my control triangle.

Comment: Can you add more information of the context like where did you encountered this question or what more do you know about the mathematical terms you used. It will be helpful for other users also to directly address the problem.

Comment: Creating a 3d facial polygon mesh..